# iterating JArray without for loop in F#

Tags: f#

I don't want to use this for loop for iterating the JArray. Is there any other method which can replace this for loop?

```
let tablesInJson = jsonModel.["tables"] :?> JArray  //Converting JOject into JArray

    for table in tablesInJson do 

    let TableName = table.["name"] :?> JValue
    let columns = table.["columns"] :?> JArray

    for col in columns do

        let name = col.["name"] :?> JValue
        let types = col.["type"] :?> JValue
        let length = col.["length"] :?> JValue

        let Result_ = sqlTableInfos 
                    |> List.tryFind (fun s -> s.TableName = TableName.ToString() && s.ColumnName = name.ToString()) 

        if Result_ = Unchecked.defaultof<_> then
            printfn "is null"
        else
            printfn "not null"
```

Comment: Why do you not want to use a for loop?

Comment: I am trying to do it in the F# way @TomasPetricek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to iterate over a collection and perform an imperative operation than using `for` loop is the idiomatic way of doing this in F# and you should just use that. After all, `for` is an F# language construct! There is a reason why it exists and the reason is that it lets you easily write code that iterates over a collection and does something for each element!

There are cases where `for` loop is not a good fit. For example, if you wanted to turn a collection of columns into a new collection with information about the tables. Then you could use `Seq.map`:

```
let tableInfos = columns |> Seq.map (fun col ->
    let name = col.["name"] :?> JValue
    let types = col.["type"] :?> JValue
    let length = col.["length"] :?> JValue
    let result = sqlTableInfos |> List.tryFind (fun s -> 
      s.TableName = TableName.ToString() && s.ColumnName = name.ToString()) 
    if result = Unchecked.defaultof<_> then None
    else Some result)
```

This looks like something you might be trying to do - but it is difficult to say. Your question does not say what is the problem that you are actually trying to solve.

Your example with `printfn` is probably misleading, because if you actually just want to print, then `for` loop is the best way of doing that.

Comment: How we convert this `for table in tablesInJson do 

    let TableName = table.["name"] :?> JValue
    let columns = table.["columns"] :?> JArray` 

for loop outside the tableInfos

Comment: Can you please help me converting both for loop as I mentioned in the Question?

Comment: @AkashVishwakarma As I mentioned in my answer, your question does not fully explain what you want to achieve. If you want to print a message, then `for` loop is the best way to do that. If you want to do something else with the information from the JSON (which I expect is the case), then you need to say _what_ you are trying to do.

Comment: If the `Result_`  is null then I want to return a string which will have the value **name** **type** and **length** and if it's not null then I want to check `!result.modelDataType.Equals(type)` this condition and return the same  **name** **type** and **length**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Seq` module to perform sequence-processing operations over the `JArray`.  In your case, I think I would probably do this for the second for loop (over the columns), but not for the outer loop.  The reason being, if you factor the code in the inner-loop out to a function, then you can use pipelining and partial application to clean up the code a bit:

```
open Newtonsoft.Json
open Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

type SqlTableInfo = {TableName: string; ColumnName: string}

let tablesInJson = JArray()
let sqlTableInfo = []

let tryFindColumn (tableName: JValue) (column: JToken) =
    let columnName = column.["name"] |> unbox<JValue>

    if sqlTableInfo |> List.exists (fun s -> s.TableName = tableName.ToString() && s.ColumnName = columnName.ToString())
    then printfn "Table %A, Column %A Found" tableName columnName 
    else printfn "Table %A, Column %A Found" tableName columnName 

for table in tablesInJson do 
    let tableName = table.["name"] |> unbox<JValue>
    table.["columns"] 
    |> unbox<JArray> 
    |> Seq.iter (tryFindColumn tableName)
```